# How to use run-time environment variables with rpm-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, rpm-maven-plugin

I am generating an RPM using rpm-maven-plugin. I would like to specify the destination directory using the relevant **run-time** env variable. The problem is that the plugin evaluates the variable during **compile** time.

For example the `${JAVA_HOME}`:

```xml
<mapping>
    <directory>${JAVA_HOME}/ext</directory>
    <sources>
        <source>
            <location>/home/user/run.sh</location>
        </source>
    </sources>
</mapping>
```

I want the directory in the RPM spec file to stay `${JAVA_HOME}/ext` and only to be evaluated during RPM installation, i.e. run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Accordind to this [documentation](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html) each environment variable is available with `env.` prefix. So you can use it like this:

```xml
<mapping>
    <directory>${env.JAVA_HOME}/ext</directory>
    <sources>
        <source>
            <location>/home/user/run.sh</location>
        </source>
    </sources>
</mapping>
```

**Note**

There are two different properties which is different.

- `${env.JAVA_HOME}` is an environment variable and it's may not be set.
- `${java.home}` is a predefined System Property which points to the Java installation folder.

Comment: Perhaps my question wan't clear enough. This is exactly why I try to avoid.
I need the `$JAVA_HOME` to stay in place, and to be evaluated during installation only.